# How to understand the Instream operator in Modelica models?

Tags: stream, modelica

I am learning how to use `instream` operator in Modelica models, but I am confused with the following [example](https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/Modelica%203.2.3/Resources/Documentation/Fluid/Stream-Connectors-Overview-Rationale.pdf), why would I need 2 equations to describe the energy balance?

Does this mean that the outlet enthalpy of `port_a` is the inlet enthalpy of `port_b` , and the outlet enthalpy of `port_b` is the inlet enthalpy of `port_a`? So the 2 equation represents that there might be  2 flow directions, and I need to take this into consideration when using `stream variables`?

When defining the momentum balance, why do I need to use the `inlet enthalpy of port_a and port_b`, I mean, there couldn't be a flow that both enters `port_a and port_b` in the same time.

[image]

Instead, in the [ModelicaTutorials](https://github.com/justnielsen/ModelicaTutorials), it uses different equations to describe the energy balance.
Does this mean that the outlet enthalpies from `port_a` and `port_b` are the same?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jack,

In the [Wiki section](https://github.com/justnielsen/ModelicaTutorials/wiki/Stream-connectors) of [ModelicaTutorials](https://github.com/justnielsen/ModelicaTutorials) there is an explanation of the difference between `inStream()` and `actualStream()`. That might help you to understand why you need two equations to describe the energy balance.

Best regards,

Rene Just Nielsen

Comment: In the first screenthso, in the code fragment`port_b_state_inflow = Medium.setState_phX(port_b.p, inStream(port_b.h_outflow))`;
why not use `port_b_state_inflow = Medium.setState_phX(port_b.p, port_b.h_outflow)` instead;
the enthalpy of port_b should be `port_b.h_outflow`, but not `inStream(port_b.h_outflow)`

Comment: because `port_b_state_inflow` represents the thermodynamical state of the *inflowing* fluid at port_b. Your suggestion does not make any sense, since `port_b.h_outflow` is unmeaningful when the flow direction is inward.

Comment: On the wiki page, it is said that the `inStream(port.h_outflow) = if port.m_flow > 0 then h_mix;`, but on some other reference material, it is said that the definition should be `inStream(port.h_outflow) =  h_mix for port.m_flow > 0 ;` is there some difference?  Here is the screenshot of the definition https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0W9D.jpg

Comment: There is no difference except that the first way of writing it is closer to Modelica syntax...